# How to put time limit in bash

Tags: bash, unix, solaris

I'm creating a simple quiz game in bash. I want to run the question with a certain time limit. How to do that? TIA

I tried using this command:

```
sleep 2m && kill $$ &
```

but it terminates the whole script.
Also: I want to display a "times up" phrase

Answer (score 3):

Similar to your original attempt, consider creating a subprocess that sleeps and sends a signal but this time [one that you catch](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_12.html):

```
handle_hup() {
  echo "Times up"
  # do more things
}

trap handle_hup SIGHUP

mypid=$$
(sleep 2m && kill -HUP $mypid)&

echo "Quiz question: ..."
```

Answer (score 2):

The [timeout](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) command may do what you want.  e.g.

```
$ timeout 120 your-game-command
```

You can check the exit status to know if the command timed out as per the docs:

> If the command times out, then exit with status 124

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't showed complete code or requirement, so providing a small piece of code only here which will wait for user's input for 10 seconds else it will print that user has timed out, you could take it as a start up point and could adjust into your script accordingly.

```
read -t 10 -p "User, please enter your Input or it will time out in 10 seconds." ; echo ; date
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue where timeout required exporting many functions and variables. Rather than exporting my entire environment...

I found the following timeout configuration easier:

```bash
MyFunction "${MyArguments[@]}" & # trailing ampersand (&) causes MyFunction to execute in background (with current environment)
zPid="$!" # bash $! provides the most recent background process id
timeout 2s bash -c wait $zPid # wait for MyFunction to finish (timeout after 2 seconds)
if [[ 124 = "$?" ]]; then # see man timeout for other error codes
   echo "MyFunction timed out."
fi
```